# In python, how to force a function argument to be of a specific Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing

In the following example

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'foo'

class B():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

a = A()
B(a)    # right
B('a')  # wrong
```

I want to do something like `B.__init__(self, a:A)` so that the argument in class B is an object of A.

Comment: There are ways, as e.g. Rahul Goswami's answer below shows you, but in general this is considered a bit of an anti-pattern in Python: a passed argument should be fine as long as it can do what you need it to do (duck-typing), rather than matching a class you have defined previously. As a compromise, you could use the new [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to suggest your class.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can always raise a `ValueError`:

```
class B():
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        if not isinstance(a, A):
            raise ValueError("a must an object of class A")
        self.a = a
```